# How to remove duplicate lines from file?

Tags: linux, files, text

I have file  for example 'a'

```
aaa
aaa
bbb
ccc
ccc
bbb
ddd
```

After executing

```
uniq a c
```

i get file 'c'

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
bbb
ddd
```

How to delete duplicate bbb lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `awk` solution:

```
awk '!a[$0]++'
```